# Probability Raining on Cloudy Day Given Not Cloudy

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, statistics

I have probability of it raining on any given day $R=0.37$, and probability of the day being cloudy $C=0.8$, it can't rain if it's not cloudy, what is the probability of it raining on a cloudy day? 
I've tried $0.37 \div 0.8$, but I'm not fully sure if this is correct. Could someone help me with this? I would like to know how I could calculate this, as well as an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Create a two-way table based on Cloudy/Not Cloudy and Rain/Not Rain.

More formally it follows from Bayes’ Theorem:

$$P(R|C) = \frac{P(C|R)P(R)}{P(C)} = \frac{1\cdot.37}{.80}$$

Comment: Could not upload the table I drew but hope it’s clear enough